# How do I connect a micro USB B-type interface to a microcontroller only for the purpose of providing power?

Tags: microcontroller, usb

I want to connect a micro USB B-type connector to the microcontroller, datasheet: [here](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/efr32mg21-datasheet.pdf). From [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/231220/how-to-connect-micro-usb-to-voltage-regulator-for-msp430-microcontroller) post I got to know that if I am not using D+ and D- lines, I need to connect them to the resistors (and they are talking about a wall charger). I will be using a 5v portable battery (a.k.a power bank), do I still need resistors? And what would be the suitable value for those resistors?

Another question that I have is regarding the 5V line, pin 1. I know that it's important to connect a decoupling capacitor to the supply lines, but is the way I connected a decoupling resistor okay? This 5V line will go to a voltage regulator further.
[image]

Thank you!

EDIT:
While looking more about it, I wanted to ask where will the shield be connected to? I saw that it should be connected to ground only as one place (and host would most probably have it) or maybe I can connect a resistor and connect to my GND on PCB. Any suggestions?

Comment: Connecting D+/D- to ground (or with eachother) is something that a charger device would do, not something that your current sinking client device needs to do. If you need less than 500mA, leave D+/D- and ID floating. For 500-900mA you could use a type-C port instead. For everything else you need to do the full USB[-PD] shenanigans with your MCU or dedicated logic chip.